# reopen "stat" question

Tags: support, reopen-closed

The question "[Extract creation date and modification time of file in SunOS?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/287114)"
was marked as a duplicate of "[stat command not found](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/287008)".

I feel that in the current state of both, that is not true. The closed question is
asking about `ctime` and `mtime`, while the open question is asking about
`atime`.

I have an answer that would apply to the closed question, but not the open one.
So can we either reopen the closed question or edit the open question to make it
more generic?

Comment: Makes sense to me, I'll reopen it.